# Transactional isolation level needed for safely incrementing ids

Tags: sql, transactions, thread-safety

I'm writing a small piece of software that is to insert records into a database used by a commercial application. The unique primary keys (ids) in the relevant table(s) are sequential, but does not seem to be set to "auto increment". Thus, I assume, I will have to find the largest id, increment it and use that value for the record I'm inserting.

In pseudo-code for brevity:

```
id = select max(id) from some_table
id++
insert into some_table values(id, othervalues...)
```

Now, if another thread started the same transaction before the first one finished its insert, you would get two identical ids and a failure when trying to insert the last one. You could check for that failure and retry, but a simpler solution might be setting an isolation level on the transaction. For this, would I need SERIALIZABLE or a lower level?

Additionally, is this, generally, a sound way of solving the problem? Are the any other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be to merge your first two lines into the insert statement:

INSERT INTO Some_Table VALUES ((Select Max(id) + 1 from Some_Table),Othervalues...)

or

INSERT INTO Some_Table SELECT st2.id, Othervalues
FROM (select max(id)+1 from Some_Table) st2

Otherwise, what you really want to do is lock this up in a transaction and prevent someone else from *reading* in that first line, and ending up with duplicate ID's... But by blocking reads, you open up a larger can of worms.

In other systems, I've seen a table used that stored the max keys - that way you could just lock the max_keys table when incrementing and your problem goes away - but sounds like you are stuck with the vendor's table structure.

Comment: Your first suggestion seems to be the simplest solution. Are these kind of statements atomic and thus absolutely thread-safe?

Comment: I'm not sure if your edit made sense...? At least I don't understand the syntax...and the first version worked. :)

Comment: Rolled it back and included both since the first version worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope [this](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/650958-duplicate-key-insertion-error-when-concurrent-users-insert-same-data-into-table) helps

Answer (score 0):

try this (using SQL Server syntax):

```
INSERT INTO some_table 
        (id, othervalues...)
    SELECT
        ISNULL(max(id),0)+1, othervalues...
        from some_table WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved similar problem for *usually* sequential (but sometimes can be overwritten and not unique) document numbers using separate table. SQL idea:

```
Declare @docno Int
Begin Tran
Select @docno=lastval+1 From docnotable With(Updlock) Where doctype='xyz'
Update docnotable Set lastval=@docno Where doctype='xyz'
... do whatever you need ...
Commit Tran
```